# TransferWise account and cancellation of hotel because of COVID-19

Tags: hotels, payment-cards, netherlands, cancellations, covid-19

Due to the on going Coronavirus outbreak, there has recently been a state of emergency declared in Czechia meaning my partner can't travel and, for this reason, I emailed a hotel I had booked in the Netherlands if I could cancel my reservation.

They will charge my EUR account on my TransferWise card at anytime. As the hotel has not responded for more than the 15 hours which they advertise, I wonder, if you would advise, that I take the money out of my TransferWise EUR account (and indeed all my accounts) and put it in my main bank account? In this way, they do not have access to any money in my (TransferWise) account.

Comment: Sure, I would do it if I am you :)

Comment: Isn’t there an option in TransferWise to temporarily block a card?

Comment: What are the terms of your booking? Was it refundable?

Comment: @jcaron Oh I see, yes there is the option of freezing my card - is this what you meant? They had verified my card before but if I freeze it today does it mean they couldn't take any funds out? The terms of the booking was non refundable and booked for two guests.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve with this? If the booking is non-refundable (or there's a cancellation fee), you'll still owe them the fee no matter what you do with your account in the meantime.

Comment: @TooTea That is true, basically I just want to ensure the hotel cannot access the money from my EUR account. Of course I had hoped my email to them would mean I would not have to owe them anything but they have not responded yet.

Comment: @TooTea By freezing the card, they will not be able to access the money and therefore may prompt them to email me to say unless we can take the funds we would have to cancel the booking. In which case, I would reply back saying yes cancel the booking.

Comment: @CAF Note that given the current situation, they're probably completely swamped with requests of all sorts, so a 15 hour response time sounds way too optimistic in my opinion. However, if you agreed to a non-refundable booking and now refuse to pay, that sounds like a pretty clear breach of contract on your side (but I'm not a lawyer).

Comment: @TooTea Yes I agree, in my mind I should do nothing but i spoke to others and they advised me to take the money out but actually I thought maybe this will mean I will go into an overdraft or something. Hopefully the hotel comes back with a positive reply shortly.

Comment: When did you book your stay? It’s unusual for non-refundable bookings not to be charged upfront at time of booking. If your booking is indeed not refundable, you have to pay for it even if you don’t want to or can’t, unless they agree otherwise. Many businesses have special waivers in place at the moment that would allow you to either postpone your booking or sometimes get a refund even for non-refundable bookings, but that is their decision, you can’t force them to accept that.

Comment: @jcaron Yes indeed, I am just worried in case they are cheeky and don't reply to my email or something or just take the money out pretending not to see the email. If they can't access the funds this would prompt them to get in touch and hopefully then the problem can be resolved and they would accept my request as a human being. But I agree, 15 hours is probably little short a time, I will wait longer and see what happens.

Comment: @CAF If the booking is not refundable, they are completely entitled to charge you for the amount of the booking, and you are liable to pay it. That's what not refundable means, and this is what travel insurance is for. There are good chances they will give you some flexibility, but that is a favour / a goodwill gesture on their part, definitely not an obligation for them, either legal or moral. They have bills to pay like everybody else, and these days every penny counts for all actors of the hospitality industry.

Comment: @jcaron Thank you for the comments

Comment: @TooTea Thank you for the comments

Comment: @CAF How is it ‘cheeky’ if a business charges for something that you have contracted to pay? IF you have a non-refundable booking (likely originally at a more favourable rate than a refundable reservation), then trying to stop them taking the money they are due is ‘cheeky’ IMHO.

Comment: So... what happened?  For others in the same situation...

Comment: @Alex The hotel kindly agreed to cancel my reservation without charge but there was a few hurdles - the hotel had agreed to cancel without charge but as I had booked via a third party (booking.com) I had to manually call the third party and after a few days I received confirmation.

Comment: @Alex But, the flights are still booked and I am tactfully waiting to see if they will be cancelled due to lockdown procedures in my country (and thereby be entitled to a refund) otherwise I will probably change flights last moment to some exotic location in a few months time (I am allowed to cancel without fee on easy jet flights but they are not offering an option to cancel) :P